# How to convert large active record data to json format - laptop get stucked and get hang during data.to_json - export, import in ROR

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, import, export, gzip

```
user_mails = UserMail.all

data = {user_mails: user_mails}

File.open("demo_data.json", "w") { |f| f.write data.to_json }

json_data['user_mails'].each do |data|
  UserMail.where(data).first_or_create!
end
```

When i trying this my system get stuck and get hang then i need to restart my system, i found that there is problem in "

```
data.to_json
```

when i do  this alone then also system get hang so there is no problem during writing file, also note that "

```
user_mails
```

contain very large data sets, that may be issues.

```
activity_logs = ActivityLog.all
consumers = Consumer.all
```

```
data = {activity_logs: activity_logs, consumers: consumers }
```

```
File.open("demo_data.json", "w") { |f| f.write data.to_json }
```

this is working fine without any problem because  these has medium data sets .
I already tryed zipping and compress but it is not working because it is problem of "data.to_json"
Please give solution how can i achive this

Comment: Can you share what happens before user_mails = user_mails.all - should this be UserMails.all ? Could you try to load the data in batches (https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html) and create the json-file yourself? You seem to iterate over the data either, so you could create the file en-route

Comment: Would it be an option to create the file directly from the database server? For PostgreSQL see here: https://alphahydrae.com/2021/02/how-to-export-postgresql-data-to-a-json-file/ - should be similiar for every other RDBMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an interesting problem.

When you call `data.to_json` it loads all the records from the database and for each row it instantiates an `ActiveRecord` Ruby object, and finally it serializes back each row to JSON. For >1000 rows this isn't efficient, especially in Ruby.

As suggested in a comment, you'll need first to query the records efficiently in batches, then append each of them (or in batches) to the JSON file. Here's a proof of concept:

```rb
File.open("demo_data.json", 'a') do |file|
  # append the header
  file.puts("{\"user_mails\": [")

  # #find_each or #find_in_batches
  user_mails.find_each do |user_mail|
    file.puts(user_mail.to_json + ",")
  end

  # append the footer
  file.puts("]}")
end
```

Note: in this POC you'll need to find a way to remove the trailing comma from the last element to get a valid JSON.

References:

- `#find_each`: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_each
- `#find_in_batches`: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_in_batches

Answer (score -1):

Yes tried and above answer is working fine, Thanks,
And i have also tried this in different approach to reach destination (transfer large set data using db_dump).
here is code :

```
 pg_dump -U user_name -d source_db -t table_name -f source_db.sql
 psql -U user_name -d destination_db -f source_db.sql
```

run this in terminal, It may not proper way but i can do my work